# SSRS Dynamic img Url

Tags: sql, url, reporting-services, barcode

A system that creates barcodes: http://www.barcodes4.me/apidocumentation

How can I use it in a table?

[image]

Or is there an easier way you can suggest?

Comment: Please have a look at this page: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with VBA,

Sample:

> ActiveSheet.Range("D3").Parent.Pictures.Insert("http://www.barcodes4.me/barcode/c39/AnyValueYouWish.png")